# How do I give a single user permissions over a schema in MySql Workbench?

Tags: permissions, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a MySql server installed on a server along with MySql Workbench.

About a year ago, I managed to do this and I felt like slapping myself as it was something so simple, but, I just can't remember what it was.

So far, I have created a new schema and created a new user.

When I click on the user and go to the `Schema Permissions` section, it is simply blank, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to populate the right hand side.

[image]

In addition, before this, I remember that MySql used to ship with the Admin tool - this was much more straight forward... but, it was old and doesn't seem to connect to the new version of MySql.

Sathya has suggested Toad, and, I will install this if no one else can come up with a solution. I am not completely against scripting a solution, but, I know this is possible and it is driving me mad that I can't figure it out - so, I would much prefer an answer that involves MySql Workbench.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your "Add Entry" button is off screen for some reason. 
[image]

Comment: OMFG... I feel like crying :( As this is (usually) headless, I leave resolution lowest as I don't want to have to assign any more memory than is necessary... but... I can't believe that this is all it was!